# What's the advantage of using 'with .. as' statement in Python?

Tags: python, with-statement

```
with open("hello.txt", "wb") as f:
    f.write("Hello Python!\n")
```

seems to be the same as

```
f = open("hello.txt", "wb")
f.write("Hello Python!\n")
f.close()
```

What's the advantage of using open .. as instead of f = ?
Is it just syntactic sugar? Just saving one line of code?

Comment: http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm

Comment: more useful reading on RAII at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In order to be equivalent to the `with` statement version, the code you wrote should look instead like this:

```
f = open("hello.txt", "wb")
try:
    f.write("Hello Python!\n")
finally:
    f.close()
```

While this might seem like syntactic sugar, it ensures that you release resources. Generally the world is more complex than these contrived examples and if you forget a `try.. except...` or fail to handle an extreme case, you have resource leaks on your hands.

The `with` statement saves you from those leaks, making it easier to write clean code. For a complete explanation, look at [PEP 343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/), it has plenty of examples.

Answer (score 13):

If `f.write` throws an exception, `f.close()` is called when you use `with` and not called in the second case.  Also `f` has a smaller scope and the code is cleaner when using `with.`

Answer (score 3):

The former still closes `f` if an exception occurs during the `f.write()`.