# Python threading in cron - lock stderr file

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, locking, stderr

I'm gonna schedule a cron with these options in my Ubuntu machine,

`* */1 * * * python /path/to/script/my_script.py --pythonpath=/path/to/script/ 1>/path/to/script/success.log 2>/path/to/script/error.log`

which will branch out `n` number of threads inside. And for logging exceptions(if raised) in each threads I'm using python's `print >>stderr`. Question is, if two threads try to write exception on same time will it cause concurrency problem? And if yes, how can I lock and release the `stderr` file from thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have half stacktrace from one thread and then the stacktrace from another one thread.

> And if yes, how can I lock and release the stderr file from thread

like every other resource shared between threads, with a lock:

```
import threading

stderr_l = threading.Lock()

def print_t(msg):
    with stderr_l:
        print msg
```

and then use only `print_t` from your threads

Comment: I don't need to invoke `acquire()` and `release()` methods?

Comment: @Babu: you can use locks in a `with` context and they are invoked for you. Look at http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/threading.html#using-locks-conditions-and-semaphores-in-the-with-statement and http://stackoverflow.com/a/2738468/230454