# Read file-names with extensions into python

Tags: python, shell, python-2.7, file-io

I am trying to read a filename that has a period in it, into this simple program..
files like "test" work, while test.txt fail. 
I kinda see why. when I type in "test.txt", only "test" appears.
when I use quotes, I get:

```
 IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "'test.txt'"
```

is there a simple way I can read file names that have things like extensions?

```
   #!/usr/bin/python
   #File Attributes
   fn=input("Enter file Name: ")
   print (fn) #added so i know why its failing.
   f = open(`fn`,'r')
   lines = f.read()
   print(lines)
   f.close()
```

Comment: The use of backticks in the `open` call is the problem. You want normal quotes there. Backticks are a deprecated alias for the `repr` function (which called on a string gets you a quoted string which is what you see in your error).

Comment: I just tried this: but it didn't work. f = open(repr(fn),'r')
am i doing it wrong?

Comment: Yes, you misunderstood my comment. `repr` is *incorrect*. You **don't** want it. You want a normal variable. My comment was partially incorrect though. You don't want quotes at all. `fn` is a variable with a string in it. `open(fn, 'r'`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the `input` function, this built_in function need a valid python input, so you can try this:

`r'test.txt'`

But you have to make sure that the `test.txt` is a valid path. I just try your code, I just change the `open` function to:

`f = open(fn,'r')`

and input like this:

`r'C:\Users\Leo\Desktop\test.txt'`

it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Using the **with...as** method as stated in this post:
    [What's the advantage of using 'with .. as' statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738365/whats-the-advantage-of-using-with-as-statement-in-python)
seems to resolve the issue.

Your final code in python3 would look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#File Attributes
fn = input("Enter file Name: ")
with open(fn, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read()
    print(lines)
```

In python2 *input("")** is replaced by **raw_input("")**:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#File Attributes
fn = raw_input("Enter file Name: ")
with open(fn, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read()
    print(lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it the following way:

```
from os.path import dirname

lines = sorted([line.strip().split(" ") for line in open(dirname(__file__) + "/test.txt","r")], key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

print [x[0] for x in lines[:3]]
print [x[0] for x in lines[3:]]
```